# How to disable Xcode 8 non-method Code Folding?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Since Xcode 8 update, my variables get folded when I try to fold everything.

Does anybody know of a way to avoid the folding of variables and only allow folding of methods? It is incredibly annoying.

Thanks for help!